# How to add image in tooltip of a button on Excel Ribbon?

Tags: excel

[image]

Does anyone know how to add image in tooltip of a button on Excel Ribbon?
I want something like the image that I have attached.

Answer (score 0):

Write some numbers into some cells and select the range:

[image]

Go to Conditional formatting -> New rule -> Format all cells based on their values

[image]

Choose Format style = Icon Sets, choose the icons you want, configure to your needs.

Comment: what I was asking is how to add an image in a tool tip not in a cell, I uploaded that image to show an example of a image in tooltip I don't want the formatting